# SQL JOINS - 3 tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, CASES, REPORTS and REPORT_DETAIL

My current report shoes all REPORTS where there is a matching CASE.  This is accomplished by

```
SELECT * FROM CASES 
JOIN REPORTS 
WHERE CASES.ID = REPORTS.ID
```

I am looking to extend this to now show additional report detail if it is available.  So show the same report, but if there is any report detail available, then tag that on the end.  I have tried a series of LEFT and RIGHT JOINS but am not getting the required dataset.

Could it be that I need to to the RIGHT JOIN once the rest of the SQL has run, and that the SQL is getting confused with where the JOIN should be?

I have tried the following but have not managed to get it to work.

```
SELECT * FROM CASES
JOIN REPORTS ON CASES.ID = REPORTS.ID
RIGHT JOIN REPORT_DETAIL ON REPORTS.DETAILID = REPORT_DETAIL.DETAILID
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM CASES C JOIN
     REPORTS R
     ON C.ID = R.ID LEFT JOIN
     REPORT_DETAIL RD
     ON R.DETAILID = RD.DETAILID;
```

This keeps all rows returned by the first `JOIN`, along with additional columns from any matching `REPORT_DETAIL` records.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  That has retained the total rows and added the extra lines.  I thought I had tried that but clearly not!  Thank you.